# JTable cell updating issue

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I got a problem I can't resolve alone and with help of other topics there. Found some 1 pretty similar but it hasn't help.

My problem is kind of tricky ones I think, I'll try to explain this as good as I can.

So, I got a JTable with couple of columns, column 2 and 3 are editable and column 4 is a product of these two (col4 = col2*col3). What I am going to do is when I edit column 2 or 3, column 4 will automaticly update it's value. I acomplished that but not fully. 
The cell is updating only when I finish editing by mouseclick. I'd like to cell react with same way if editing is finished by ENTER key.

I was trying a little bit with:

```
if(recipeTable.getCellEditor()!=null)recipeTable.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
```

but it isn't changing anything.

Here is my code:

```
recipeTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(COLUMN_HEADLINE, 0) {

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) 
        {
            model.updateTotalPriceInTable(recipeTable);
            return (column == 2) || (column == 3);
        }
    };
```

And:

```
public void updateTotalPriceInTable(JTable table)
{
    double totalPrice;
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    for(int i = 0; i < tableModel.getRowCount(); i++)
    {
        totalPrice = Double.parseDouble(tableModel.getValueAt(i, 2).toString()) * Double.parseDouble(tableModel.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
        tableModel.setValueAt(totalPrice, i, 4);
    }
    tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Ok I figured it out, that is code the code that resolved my problem:

```
@Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column)
        {
        Vector rowVector = (Vector)dataVector.elementAt(row);
        rowVector.setElementAt(aValue, column);
        rowVector.setElementAt(Double.parseDouble((String) rowVector.get(2))*Double.parseDouble((String) rowVector.get(3)), 4);
        fireTableDataChanged();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `setValueAt(...)` method of your TableModel. You invoke super.setValueAt(...) to save the data normally.

Then whenever the data in column 2 or 3 changes, you then calculate the value of column 4 and update the model.

Comment: What should I actually change in overriden method comparing to default one?

Comment: Ok I figured it out, I override setValueAt like this: [link](http://wklej.org/id/1336299/)

Comment: @bbZ, update your question to show the code you used. Don't use an external link.

Comment: @bbz, that is not a very good solution. You should not be accessing the Vector directly. YOu should not be invoking firstTableDataChanged since you did not change the entire model. I suggest you should invoke `super.setValueAt()` to invoke the default code to update the model. Then I suggest you need an `if statement` to check if column 2/3 changed. If so then you calculate the value of column 4 and invoke the super.setValueAt(...) method for column 4. It will then invoke the proper fireXXX method.